# multiple select in ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to select values from 2db.

```
image_db => id, image_adress, category, product_id;
product_db => id, name, price;
```

I want to select the images from a particular category and for each image the data of the product

what should i do?

this is correct?

```
$select  = $image_model->select()
                       ->where('category = ?',$category)->from(array('i'=>'image_db'),
array('adress','product_id'))->join(array('p'=>'product_db'), 'i.product_id'='p.id');
```

Comment: image_db and product_db are tables in a single DB or two different databases?

Answer (score 1):

assuming they are both in same database,
it seems to be correct,
but i think you are using it from controller,

but you can use it from model which will be better hence zend is an MVC,

```
 public function getProducts($category)
{       

        $sql=$this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array('i'=>'imagemaster'),array())               
            ->join(array('p'=>'projectmaster'),'i.project_id=p.id',array()) 

            ->where('category = ?',$category)                  
            ->group('p.id');          

        $resultSet = $this->fetchAll($sql);
        return $resultSet;
}
```

havent tested it but it should work.. hope it helps..